# SQL Server, getting "for xml" value

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, for-xml

I think this one's pretty straightforward, but I can't seem to find it answered.

I'm running a query on SQL Server 2005 with `for xml, elements` at the end to return the result as XML.

```
select top 10 title, pubdate, description, link
from rssfeed item
for xml auto, elements
```

I'm running the query from a classic ASP page.  Normally to get the results from a column, I'd use `rs.Fields.Item("colName")`.  The problem is, with `for xml`, the column name is a long string like `XML_F52E2B61-...`.

I tried `rs.Fields(0).value`. That weirdly returned the names of the columns in the query separated by question marks, not the XML.  My output is:

```
?title?pubdate?description?link?item?L???
```

I tested my query in Management Studio, and the XML looks alright.  Is there a way to read this value into classic ASP?

Comment: Found a Microsoft link (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187561.aspx).  They suggest `rs(0)`.  Tried it.  Same question mark-delimited result.

Comment: The link uses a connection string with `DataTypeCompatibility=80`.  Tried it.  No luck.

Comment: The link uses `Provider=SQLNCLI`.  I was using `Provider=SQLOLEDB`.  Tried it.  No luck.  Same result.

Comment: Updated link for SQL 2005 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187561%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

Comment: Found a post on DBA.SE comparing SQLNCLI and SQLOLEDB. (http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/2833/9553).  The answer mentions a limited feature set in ADO, which is what I'm using.  Possibly the culprit?

Comment: The link suggests MDAC 2 version 6.0 or higher.  I have the latest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the [answer in SQL Server forum](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic663872-21-1.aspx#bm663984).  There's probably a cleaner way to do this, but the idea from the post is to convert the XML to a varchar(max).

```
DECLARE @xmlout as varchar(max);
DECLARE @X as Xml;

set @X = (select top 10 title, pubdate, description, link
from rssfeed item
for xml auto, elements);

select @xmlout = cast(@X as varchar(max));
select @xmlout;
```

After running the query, I'm then using `rs(0)` to read the returned value.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer by @dangowans is very good. I reached here searching for a solution for a similar problem.

However, I could manage without moving to a stored procedure kind of thing and managed using a single query like this:

```
Select k=(select top 10 title, pubdate, description, link
from rssfeed item
for xml auto, elements)
```

And it returned me the XML output as `varchar`.